# Missing object when load scene using asset bundle

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, assetbundle

So I was trying to make an apps with unity with assetbundle and it have no problem when I run it on PC and Android device. But when I run it on IOS, some of 3D objects are missing, the only missing 3D object is object with skinned mesh renderer.

Is it because something wrong with asset bundle script? Because when I run it on unity on mac, the error didn't occur

Comment: Are AssetBundles cross-platform? http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/abfaq.html